# Is there a hook for rcirc, similar to erc-insert-modify-hook?

Tags: regex, twitter, emacs, elisp, irc

I was porting erc-tweet to rcirc and succeded in porting the scraping logic.

```
(require 'request)
(request "https://twitter.com/spacemanaki/status/392097918812839937"
         :parser 'buffer-string
         :success (function*
                   (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
                     (save-excursion
                       (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*request demo*")
                         (erase-buffer)
                         (insert data)
                         (goto-char (point-min))
                         (kill-region
                          (point)
                          (progn (search-forward
                                  "<p class=\"js-tweet-text tweet-text\">")
                                 (point)))
                         (kill-region
                          (progn (search-forward "</p>")
                                 (search-backward "</p>")
                                 (point))
                          (point-max))
                         (kill-region (point-min) (point-max))))
                     (yank))))
```

And the regexp on when to start the replacement can be reused from erc-tweet `"https?://twitter.com/.+/status/[0-9]+"`. The question is now where do I have to hook function in question, I can't find anything similar to erc-insert-modify-hook in rcirc.

Answer (score 1):

As long as I can see, you have

```
rcirc-mode-hook, 
rcirc-activity-hooks  
rcirc-receive-message-hooks
rcirc-print-hooks
rcirc-sentinel-hooks
rcirc-authenticate-hook
rcirc-update-activit-string-hook
```

Check with the help of M-x "C-h v" on the use of each.